# How to configure Mac OS X Snow Leopard to automatically connect to my Bluetooth Speakers for sound output?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, audio, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth speaker that I use for audio output on Snow Leopard (the Sony SRS-BT100).  Generally I like it, except for one thing:

When my laptop wakes from sleep it does not automatically connect to the speaker.  I have to manually go to the bluetooth menu and select `SRS-BT100 -> Use as Audio Device (Stereo)`.

Is there a way to configure Snow Leopard to automatically connect to my bluetooth speaker if it's available?

Comment: i did not try it yet, but you could use apple script see [some guide to applescript/automator](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/applescript/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript/) and especially [pairing bluetooth thing with applescript](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=22149) (should give you the right directions) to get it run at start up, ask google nicely e.g. [run applescript at startup](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/running-windows-anything-else-your-mac/76648-run-applescript-start-up.html)